# how to fix UnsatisfiedDependencyException in spring framework When used @Query

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have created WEB services using springboot, I`ve using simple methode out JpaRepository for example .findAll()  and everything was working normally.
When I tried to use @Request - JPQL of SQL request the problem occurred.

I`ve tried one simple request @Query("SELECT content FROM qcm.tabledeteste t where t.id = ?1")

That was a simple example but my real goal was to update the data

in DAO 
...

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface TesterDao extends  JpaRepository<Tester, String> { 
    @Query("SELECT content FROM autosv.tester t where t.id = ?1")
    String  testerQuery(String id); 
}
```

in controller name : TesterController
....

```
TesterDao tDao;
@GetMapping(value = "/testerQuery")
    public String  testerQuery() {
        String t = tDao.testerQuery("7");       
        return t;
}
```

...

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error
 creating bean with name 'TesterController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
 through field 'tDao'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
 with name 'TesterDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method 

public abstract java.lang.String 

com.example.qcm.qcm.dao.TabledetesteDao.getTabledetestQuery(java.lang.String)


!
```

......

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: is not mapped
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Class name Tester instead of autosv.tester in your query.